# Why is my return on page.on function not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return, puppeteer

In my puppeteer/javascript code below I am receiving a different result to what is expected. I am not sure why?

I am expecting the **"myjson"** value to be returned inside of the **"price_json"** however it is returning all the elements from the browser as you can see from the actual result.

I'm not sure If I'm missing basic javascript knowledge here however I've done the same thing with a page.evaluate and that seems to be working fine....

**Code -**

```
const price_json = await page.on('response', async (response, i) => {
        const myjson = await response.json();
        console.log("inside of the page.on")
        console.log(myjson)
        console.log("inside (end) of the page.on")
        return myjson
  }, i);

  console.log(price_json)
```

**Expected Result -** (myjson looks like this)

```
{ unit_price: '$39.65',
  carton_price: '$237.92',
  stock_code: '66121' }
```

**Actual Result -** (price_json after the return...)

```
  _events: [Object: null prototype] { response: [AsyncFunction] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _closed: false,
  _client:
   CDPSession {
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        'Fetch.requestPaused': [Function: bound _onRequestPaused],
        'Fetch.authRequired': [Function: bound _onAuthRequired],
        'Network.requestWillBeSent': [Function: bound _onRequestWillBeSent],
        'Network.requestServedFromCache': [Function: bound _onRequestServedFromCache],
        'Network.responseReceived': [Function: bound _onResponseReceived],
        'Network.loadingFinished': [Function: bound _onLoadingFinished],
        'Network.loadingFailed': [Function: bound _onLoadingFailed],
        'Page.frameAttached': [Function],
        'Page.frameNavigated': [Function],
        'Page.navigatedWithinDocument': [Function],
        'Page.frameDetached': [Function],
        'Page.frameStoppedLoading': [Function],
        'Runtime.executionContextCreated': [Function],
        'Runtime.executionContextDestroyed': [Function],
        'Runtime.executionContextsCleared': [Function],
        'Page.lifecycleEvent': [Function],
        'Target.attachedToTarget': [Function],
        'Target.detachedFromTarget': [Function],
        'Page.domContentEventFired': [Function],
        'Page.loadEventFired': [Function],
        'Runtime.consoleAPICalled': [Function],
        'Runtime.bindingCalled': [Function],
        'Page.javascriptDialogOpening': [Function],
        'Runtime.exceptionThrown': [Function],
        'Inspector.targetCrashed': [Function],
        'Performance.metrics': [Function],
        'Log.entryAdded': [Function],
        'Page.fileChooserOpened': [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 28,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _callbacks: Map {},
     _connection:
      Connection {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 4,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _url:
         'ws://127.0.0.1:58923/devtools/browser/89cbedaf-2ce2-4df8-b52b-3836987b2521',
        _lastId: 87,
        _callbacks: Map {},
        _delay: 0,
        _transport: [WebSocketTransport],
        _sessions: [Map],
        _closed: false },
     _targetType: 'page',
     _sessionId: '45363630A29A7F3799E8612DDB0C79B9' },
  _target:
   Target {
     _targetInfo:
      { targetId: 'FB19D7C032DE5773F35827E7AECD9082',
        type: 'page',
        title: 'https://www.****.com.au/customers/orders',
        url: 'https://www.*****.com.au/customers/orders',
        attached: true,
        browserContextId: '10EE70BFE005227DB58E3291908CB868' },
     _browserContext:
      BrowserContext {
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connection: [Connection],
        _browser: [Browser],
        _id: null },
     _targetId: 'FB19D7C032DE5773F35827E7AECD9082',
     _sessionFactory: [Function],
     _ignoreHTTPSErrors: false,
     _defaultViewport: { width: 800, height: 600 },
     _screenshotTaskQueue: TaskQueue { _chain: [Promise] },
     _pagePromise: Promise { [Circular] },
     _workerPromise: null,
     _initializedCallback: [Function],
     _initializedPromise: Promise { true },
     _closedCallback: [Function],
     _isClosedPromise: Promise { <pending> },
     _isInitialized: true },
  _keyboard:
   Keyboard {
     _client:
      CDPSession {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 28,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _callbacks: Map {},
        _connection: [Connection],
        _targetType: 'page',
        _sessionId: '45363630A29A7F3799E8612DDB0C79B9' },
     _modifiers: 0,
     _pressedKeys: Set {} },
  _mouse:
   Mouse {
     _client:
      CDPSession {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 28,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _callbacks: Map {},
        _connection: [Connection],
        _targetType: 'page',
        _sessionId: '45363630A29A7F3799E8612DDB0C79B9' },
     _keyboard:
      Keyboard { _client: [CDPSession], _modifiers: 0, _pressedKeys: Set {} },
     _x: 1157.59375,
     _y: 422.09375,
     _button: 'none' },
  _timeoutSettings:
   TimeoutSettings { _defaultTimeout: null, _defaultNavigationTimeout: null },
  _touchscreen:
   Touchscreen {
     _client:
      CDPSession {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 28,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _callbacks: Map {},
        _connection: [Connection],
        _targetType: 'page',
        _sessionId: '45363630A29A7F3799E8612DDB0C79B9' },
     _keyboard:
      Keyboard { _client: [CDPSession], _modifiers: 0, _pressedKeys: Set {} } },
  _accessibility:
   Accessibility {
     _client:
      CDPSession {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 28,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _callbacks: Map {},
        _connection: [Connection],
        _targetType: 'page',
        _sessionId: '45363630A29A7F3799E8612DDB0C79B9' } },
  _frameManager:
   FrameManager {
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        [Symbol(Events.FrameManager.FrameAttached)]: [Function],
        [Symbol(Events.FrameManager.FrameDetached)]: [Function],
        [Symbol(Events.FrameManager.FrameNavigated)]: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 3,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _client:
      CDPSession {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 28,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _callbacks: Map {},
        _connection: [Connection],
        _targetType: 'page',
        _sessionId: '45363630A29A7F3799E8612DDB0C79B9' },
     _page: [Circular],
     _networkManager:
      NetworkManager {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 4,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _client: [CDPSession],
        _ignoreHTTPSErrors: false,
        _frameManager: [Circular],
        _requestIdToRequest: [Map],
        _requestIdToRequestWillBeSentEvent: Map {},
        _extraHTTPHeaders: {},
        _offline: false,
        _credentials: null,
        _attemptedAuthentications: Set {},
        _userRequestInterceptionEnabled: false,
        _protocolRequestInterceptionEnabled: false,
        _userCacheDisabled: false,
        _requestIdToInterceptionId: Map {} },
     _timeoutSettings:
      TimeoutSettings { _defaultTimeout: null, _defaultNavigationTimeout: null },
     _frames: Map { 'FB19D7C032DE5773F35827E7AECD9082' => [Frame] },
     _contextIdToContext: Map { 5 => [ExecutionContext], 6 => [ExecutionContext] },
     _isolatedWorlds: Set { '__puppeteer_utility_world__' },
     _mainFrame:
      Frame {
        _frameManager: [Circular],
        _client: [CDPSession],
        _parentFrame: null,
        _url: 'https://www.*****.com.au/customers/orders',
        _id: 'FB19D7C032DE5773F35827E7AECD9082',
        _detached: false,
        _loaderId: 'D87D50CD254B4D51BD687A720F36BFCA',
        _lifecycleEvents: [Set],
        _mainWorld: [DOMWorld],
        _secondaryWorld: [DOMWorld],
        _childFrames: Set {},
        _name: undefined,
        _navigationURL: 'https://www.*******.com.au/customers/orders' } },
  _emulationManager:
   EmulationManager {
     _client:
      CDPSession {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 28,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _callbacks: Map {},
        _connection: [Connection],
        _targetType: 'page',
        _sessionId: '45363630A29A7F3799E8612DDB0C79B9' },
     _emulatingMobile: false,
     _hasTouch: false },
  _tracing:
   Tracing {
     _client:
      CDPSession {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 28,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _callbacks: Map {},
        _connection: [Connection],
        _targetType: 'page',
        _sessionId: '45363630A29A7F3799E8612DDB0C79B9' },
     _recording: false,
     _path: '' },
  _pageBindings: Map {},
  _coverage:
   Coverage {
     _jsCoverage:
      JSCoverage {
        _client: [CDPSession],
        _enabled: false,
        _scriptURLs: Map {},
        _scriptSources: Map {},
        _eventListeners: [],
        _resetOnNavigation: false },
     _cssCoverage:
      CSSCoverage {
        _client: [CDPSession],
        _enabled: false,
        _stylesheetURLs: Map {},
        _stylesheetSources: Map {},
        _eventListeners: [],
        _resetOnNavigation: false } },
  _javascriptEnabled: true,
  _viewport: { width: 1920, height: 1080 },
  _screenshotTaskQueue:
   TaskQueue {
     _chain:
      Promise {
        <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52 00 00 07 80 00 00 04 38 08 06 00 00 00 e8 d3 c1 43 00 00 00 01 73 52 47 42 00 ae ce 1c e9 00 00 20 00 ... > } },
  _workers: Map {},
  _fileChooserInterceptionIsDisabled: false,
  _fileChooserInterceptors: Set {} }
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is 2 years old and hopefully you found the answer. Seeing that this has over a hundred views so far...

What you have in the second console.log is the `page` object itself and not the response. You'll want to do a closure if you want the response in the upper scope, like:

```
let price_json;
await page.on('response', async (response, i) => {
  price_json = await response.json();
}, i);
console.log(price_json);
```